# How to change element colours in the SoundCloud Mini HTML5 player

Tags: html, parameters, widget, soundcloud

We Embedded the SoundCloud HTML5 Mini Player on our website.
We are trying to change the colours of the player's elements without success.
Is there a way to change the BG colour as well as the text colours to fit our site's colour pallete?

Answer (score 2):

You can provide a `color` parameter when embedding widget:

```
https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/6981096&color=2b877f
```

This will make widget themed with the provided color.

If you'd like more customization you'd need to build a custom player with a library like [SoundManager2](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) or [Audio5JS](http://zohararad.github.com/audio5js/) or by using [SoundCloud JavaScript SDK](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks) that would play sounds from SoundCloud.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is only half an answer. You need to set the player's visual tag to false. And you cannot change the background, as of April 2015.